# Bootstrap - Add a widget to side of the page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I wanna add a simple text box to side of my page.

[image: Img]

I have a table. So when the widget has added the table has to be decrease it's width.
Thanks in advance!

```
                                                                                                   .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col">
    Your table
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    Widget here
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you need to create a layout (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/layout/) with properly setup grid system and have a place for your widget. So checkout the layout and grid system in bootsrap first to understand.